# Error: cut: the delimiter must be a single character in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to cut the first and the second column from **studata.txt** and the second column from **studata1.txt**.

**studata.txt**:

```
1 a 10
2 b 20
3 c 30
```

**studata1.txt**:

```
i si
co oi
me zi
```

Here is my bash file:

```
cut -d -f -2 studata.txt >tmp1
cut -d -f 2- studata1.txt > tmp2
paste tmp1 tmp2 > c.txt
cat c.txt
```

Error:

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to *escape* the space when it's used as a parameter i.e.:

```
cut -d \  -f -2 studata.txt > tmp1
```

N.B. There are 2 spaces after `\`. The first one is escaped and represents the argument for the `-d` option, while the second one delimits it from the `-f` option.

You can also put it between *single quotes*:

```
cut -d ' ' -f -2 studata.txt > tmp1
```

or between *double quotes*:

```
cut -d " " -f -2 studata.txt > tmp1
```

Explanations are available in the [Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) section of the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/):

> [Escape Character](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html): How to remove the special meaning from a single character.
>
> [Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html): How to inhibit all interpretation of a sequence of characters.
>
> [Double Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html): How to suppress most of the interpretation of a sequence of characters.

Comment: what does '\' signify?

Comment: \ is an escape character which means that the following character is not interpreted in the usual way, but it's taken ad litteram. Space is a parameter delimiter normally, but if you put \ before it, it becomes part of a parameter.

Comment: I'm struggling with this, because I need it in a script:
current_status=$(curl -I https://www.example.com 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2)

What can I do?

Comment: @JonZangitu `status=$(curl --silent -I example.com | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)` works fine for me ($status is 200).